# Android: is there a standard way to provide password protection for an app?

Tags: android, password-protection

I'd like to provide password protection for my app. Is there a standard way to do this on Android? A standard place to store the password, and provide a way to set, change, delete, and/or recover the password if the user forgets it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard password protection available for applications to implement via an API. The lockscreen tends to serve as that purpose (from Android's perspective).

Comment: That's unfortunate. The lock-screen locks too much. My users would like a more granular locking mechanism.